# Grails domain reload missing attributes

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm working inside of a service and I have the following two calls:

```
def user = User.get(2)
user = user.get(1)
```

This example is contrived, but it illustrates my issue.  For the first line I get the user with an id of 2.  At this point I have a fully populated domain object and all is well. The fields are populated in the database, so it's not as obvious as missing data.  If I call `User.get(1)`first I'll have a correctly populated domain object. However, when I make the second call (the reassignment) I get a semi populated record.  I'm missing the User's firstName, lastName, and email fields.  This seems like a pretty simple use case and I've never had this issue in the past.  Am I doing something really dumb here?  Has something like this happened to anyone else?

Some field definitions:

```
String username
String emailAddress
String firstName
String lastName
String password
String photoUrl
String title
String contactPhone
```

Corresponding constraints:

```
username(blank: false, unique: true)
photoUrl(nullable: true)
title(nullable: true)
contactPhone(nullable: true)
welcomeText(nullable: true)
emailAddress(blank: false, nullable: false)
firstName(blank: false)
lastName(blank: false)
```

Comment: Do values for those fields actually exist in the database? It's possible to get objects out of the db that won't validate.

Comment: Yes, the fields exist in the database.  If I 'get' each id it works fine. It's only when I try the reassignment that I have the issue.  It's really weird.

Comment: This appears to be a caching issue.  If I pass a domain object into the service and then try to reload the same domain object, I only get partial results. I can load any other record except for the record passed into the service.  Weird, but there it is.